# import winreg while retaining linux support

Tags: python, python-3.x, winreg

I have a python 3 application which currently supports windows and linux. I want to build some windows specific functionality which requires me to import winreg.

However the `import winreg` statement prevents the code from being executed under linux.

How can i use winreg without breaking the code under linux?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manuel, in case you haven't reached the solution yet, although I presume you did, but maybe someone else may found it useful.

Fence the code with:

```
if 'posix' in sys.builtin_module_names:
    # *nix
    ...
```

or:

```
if 'nt' in sys.builtin_module_names:
    # Win
    ...
```

At least I did so on several occasions writing x-platform apps in python 2.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `importlib` to test if `winreg` exists.

```py
winreg_exists = importlib.find_loader('winreg')
if winreg_exists:
    import winreg
...
if winreg_exists:
    # do winreg stuff
```